# ExtJS: how to toggle an html view

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, onclick, toggle

I have an HTML code with a button. When the button is clicked, certain objects should toggle. This isn't working currently.

```
var contentString = '<a href="#" onclick="someFunction()">' + testVariable + '</a><br><button onclick="document.getElementById(\'demo\').toggle()">BUTTON TOGGLE</button><br><p id= "demo">' + hideVariableOnToggle + '</p>';

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: '<div style="min-height:50px; color:black; width: 300px;">' + contentString + '</div>'
});
```

I get the following error

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).toggle is not a function    

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Also, how can I access the element by ID? Currently I get null for all my attempts

```
Ext.get('demo') //null
document.getElementById('demo')//null
Ext.getCmp('demo')//null
```

Comment: You are trying to call `toggle` on a "P" [dom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element). There is no such method.

Comment: Maybe, the `.toggle()` you are trying to use is part of jQuery (see [this link](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) ), in that case add a reference to jquery library before calling it.

Comment: I tried something like <p> <div id= \'demo\'>' + obj.other_sites + '</div></p> and that too didn't work. How do I know there where the toggle() is applicable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element P you have is a Html element and has no implementation for the toggle() function, unless you are using JQuery. You can try changing the *display* property to hide or show the object

```
function toggle(obj){
    obj.style.display = (obj.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
}
```

You can use this function in the button:

```
<button onclick="toggle(document.getElementById('demo'));">BUTTON TOGGLE</button>
```

You can see this example
http://jsfiddle.net/bocanegra_carlos/eus14g3t/

Comment: Thanks @Carlos                                     document.getElementById(divId).style.visibility                                                            works for me